Anaconda don't work in VSC GitBash terminal wrong path
Normal GitBash in Windows:
[GitBash in Windows][1]
$ echo $PATH
/c/Users/Krystian/anaconda3:/c/Users/Krystian/anaconda3/Library/mingw-w64/bin:/c/Users/Krystian/anaconda3/Library/usr/bin:/c/Users/Krystian/anaconda3/Library/bin:/c/Users/Krystian/anaconda3/Scripts:/c/Users/Krystian/anaconda3/bin:/c/Users/Krystian/anaconda3/condabin:/c/Users/Krystian/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/Krystian/bin:

Same command but in GitBash Terminal in Visual Studio Code when conda env is selected
[GitBash in VSCode][2]
$ echo $PATH
C:\Users\Krystiannaconda3vs\main;C:\Users\Krystiannaconda3vs\main\Library\mingw-w6in;C:\Users\Krystiannaconda3vs\main\Library\usin;C:\Users\Krystiannaconda3vs\main\Librarin;C:\Users\Krystiannaconda3vs\main\Scripts;C:\Users\Krystiannaconda3vs\maiin;C:\Users\Krystiannaconda3/c/Users/Krystian/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:

I can not execute any commannd related to conda when I'am using a GitBash in VSC.
For instance:
[Conda command](https://i.sstatic.net/EDodhQqZ.png)
$ conda deactivate

bash: C:\Users\Krystiannaconda3\Scripts: No such file or directory

Why GitBash doesn't work in VSC while Anaconda Env is selected as a Python Interpreter? It looks like there is a wrong path \Krystiannaconda3/ but in env setting everything is correct.
I tried to reinstall everything, respectivelly VSCode, Git, Anaconda, and still encounter this problem.


in env setting everything is correct* Do you mean in your environment variables settings?


Exactly, in this file which is read-only paths are correct

also do you have any hidden files called .bashrc in your user folder? (probably C:\Users\Krystian\.bashrc but you must be sure to show hidden files in explorer.

In my user folder there is no file  .bashrc but there is .bash_profile which was created as a result of conda init bash executed in Anaconda Prompt

hmmm probably empty but is anything in that file?

>>> conda initialize >>>
!! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
if [ -f '/c/Users/Krystian/anaconda3/Scripts/conda.exe' ]; then
eval "$('/c/Users/Krystian/anaconda3/Scripts/conda.exe' 'shell.bash' 'hook')"
fi
<<< conda initialize <<<
Above its content

backup that file (copy it as .bash_profile_backup) then remove the contents and try again... (restart VSCode)

I did and received
CondaError: Run 'conda init' before 'conda activate'
executed conda init and message No action taken, then executed conda init bash and received modified      C:\Users\Krystian.bash_profile and the content of that file is again the same like before.

Okay yeah it did look like it was configured correctly. This is bizarre. Something is altering your Path when you start vscode. Is anything in your vscode settings.json - although I guess not if you just reinstalled.

I think the same way, but can't trace what is altering path.
settings.json looks seamlessly
settings.json

You probably should check your environment variables again - both user and system, just to be sure - in the search box in the taskbar type environment variables and look for both types.

The setting for windows terminal automation profile is showing an error ? Squiggly line. It might be a bad setting try removing it too.

In the search box nothing pops up after typing environment variables

Its kind of weird that your settings have "Git Bash" as the default terminal. I've always seen "GitBash". I'd actually recommend remove all integrated terminal settings in settings.json and start over with setting your default terminal (you can use the command palette for this with the command Terminal: Select Default Profile

what did you mean by Exactly, in this file which is read-only paths are correct when you were referring to your env  ... what file?

OK I deleted those 2 lines from settings.json after set my default terminal the way you advised.
It was file that contribute to terminal's environment
That file

I'm not going to download files. Can you say the name of the file, what it is for, and what is inside it (if its not too much - presumably, environment configuration?)

Yes, it is environemnt configuration, extract from there:

`PATH=C:\Users\Krystian\anaconda3\envs\main;C:\Users\Krystian\anaconda3\envs\main\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\Krystian\anaconda3\envs\main\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\Krystian\anaconda3\envs\main\Library\bin;C:\Users\Krystian\anaconda3\envs\main\Scripts;C:\Users\Krystian\anaconda3\envs\main\bin;C:\Users\Krystian\anaconda3\condabin;C:\


I would guess that all those single backslashes need to be escaped or in other words you need double backslashes ... whatever this file is. It doesn't seem necessary at all to me as you have already initialized bash with your conda init function ... that is enough to handle the need for bash to be able to find conda (but ... maybe you have other things in there besides).

Unfortunately, I cannnot replace \ with \ since there is a message Cannot edit it in read-only editor
File's part1
File's part2

Initializing bash with conda init function should be enough to handle with and find ans use conda in GitBash, but it does not work for me

$ conda init results in
bash: C:\Users\Krystiannaconda3\Scripts: No such file or directory
Still something alters Path

This "read only file" ... What is that file? Why is it there? Where is it?

I have to click at Show environment contribution in Terminal section, then it appears. I do relaunch but it doesn't help att all, GitBash not workig, even after reload.
Terminal

What extensions have you installed? I have never seen a "Show Environment contribution" in Terminal section. You probably want to disable all extensions when you have weird problems anyway (that is probably not really a "file" either, btw - just some visual output for you to inspect.

I have never seen a "Show Environment contribution" it pops up after I change Python Interpreter from non Conda (local downloaded from python.org) to Conda and likewise.
With regard to extensions, conda want to contribute to terminal not others extension.
Check. I also want to say that a few days ago everything was working, I was able to use GitBash, this problem appeared yesterday.

Any extension I have installed shouldn't be altering my path

whats in the init file you have in your Terminal output at the top? that .sh file that seems to be invoked when you start bash.

in that folder are 3 files: Files

shellintegration-bash.sh is a very large file, 318 lines, how can I show you that

I meant the file after --init-file : C:\Users\Krystian\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app/out/vs/workbench/contrib/terminal/browser/media/shelIntegration-bash.sh

yes, it's another potential source of startup configuration for bash (also another strange file ... and in a strange place)

This file contains 318 lines, how can I show you its content

You could add it to your question description (edit your question)

Anyway, the main thing is to look there for any PATH configuration...

Its normally not what you want to do but you might try disabling shell integration.

I'm to running out of ideas now though I'm afraid. If its any consolation I switched last year from primarily using gitbash to using Powershell 7 as my primary shell in VSCode and I have found it be be perfectly fine. Do you have similar problems with Powershell or other terminals in VSCode?

This file doesn't contain any PATH config. I'm also running out of ideas how to tackle this problem, especially when reinstall don't help.
I don't have similar problems with Powershell in VSCode, however I hadn't had problems with GitBash untill yesterday.

The slashes we saw in some output suggests to me that some file somewhere has backslash a and should have double backslash a, since it is precisely \a that is falling out of your path entries - but where? how? Don't know. Might try downgrading VSCode or any recently upgraded extensions in case its a massive bug in the latest version - though that's a long shot as this is not the kind of thing I would expect to be revised or revised incorrectly. If other terminals are okay ... seems to suggest configuration error somewhere in gitbash, bash, or conda.

Yes but which file...
I also want to mention that when I launch VSCode via Anaconda Navigator, GitBash works correctly however, when open normal VSCode GitBash don't work. Is there any relationship between them?

Both versions are 1.89.0

Its possible they are independent installations but I'm not sure. I'm not a fan of anaconda. I use miniconda instead - I don't need or want 10,000 packages installed - just conda package management.

'seems to suggest configuration error somewhere in gitbash, bash, or conda.' thus I reinstalled them all but no effect achieved.

I guess probably if you can start vscode by itself without anaconda, and you only installed anaconda not vscode, then that proves its the same. But anaconda started through anaconda navigator is very like to have some startup configuration or environment settings that you don't get otherwise.

Ok, maybe I should try miniconda insetad of anaconda. Nonetheless this issue has been nagigng me since yesterday when it suddenly stopped working. I didn't update anything in VSCode either Anaconda.

okay, try uninstalling anaconda and vscode and (even gitbash maybe) and then install gitbash, vscode, and finally miniconda: https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/install/uninstall/

And it's bizzare that it used to operate seamlessly before.

Look around for any remaining anaconda or conda files in your home directory (including hidden files in .config) and delete them after you uninstall anaconda. same for your Users/you/appdata/local/... directories

It is. You win the prize for the most bizarre anaconda problems I've seen in a while

https://docs.anaconda.com/free/miniconda/miniconda-install/ after installing miniconda you need to create an environment for yourself (there is a base environment you can use that if you want by I always create a working environment as my "normal everyday" -- I call it pydev -- and leave my base environment alone.

With miniconda you need to be familiar with basic conda commands to manage environments in the terminal: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html and https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf

Finally with miniconda once you have it working (assuming it does) you will need to install the packages you want to use. I always install in my working environment (or base environment if I intend to use that for everyday work) common packages like numpy and pandas. If you use jupyter you need to install that too, and you may need to make sure jupyter is aware of your environments: https://medium.com/@jy.wong.xeron/managing-jupyter-notebooks-and-conda-environments-6b8c627e0c2f (i.e., if you don't see your env in the list of available environments when you are in jupyter itself).

Okay, I do what you suggest. Anyway, I am going to try to fix that problem with Anaconda in the nearest future. I'll let you know, if I overcome that battle.

Great I'd love to know!

Good luck to you!

UPDATE:
I rolled back to version 1.88 and can use conda in the VS Code terminal again!
I am having a similar issue.  It appears the backslashes are removing the next character if it is lowercase.  I believe this started happening after a recent vs code update.  I may try to roll back.
$ conda
bash: C:\Userswilsnaconda3\Scripts: No such file or directory


I had the same problem, /a is missing in path. It is caused by Microsoft python extension for VSCode modifying path. Had to disable it as a workaround.
It must be a VSCode bug.

A temporary work-around that works for me is the following:

As others mention, use command prompt as a default
Add the following to ~/.bashrc, so if I need to use conda and git bash in vs code, I can, after calling fixconda:

fixconda() {
# At the end of .bashrc
if [[ "$TERM_PROGRAM" = "vscode" ]]; then

# Change for your user name below. Find this out from 
# echo "$PATH" > path.txt
# cat -A path.txt
 export PATH=$(echo "$PATH" | sed 's|C:\\Users\\grant\x07naconda3\x1bnvs||g')

 unset -f conda
 source ~/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
fi


# Define the activate function explicitly if needed
if ! command -v conda activate &>/dev/null; then
 source "${CONDA_ROOT}/bin/activate"
fi
}

There might be some fix that elaborates on my second option a bit more, but I haven't found a way for it to both automatically run and to fix the issue.

This problem may be caused by the incompatibility between VS Code's Git Bash terminal and Anaconda's environment variables on Windows systems. In Git Bash, paths are used Unix-style (using forward slashes /), while Anaconda may use Windows-style paths (using backslashes ****) when setting environment variables.
You could try to use PowerShell or CMD in VSCode.
Another way is to manually modify the environment variable. Before starting VS Code, you can set the PATH environment variable in Git Bash by command export PATH="/c/Users/Krystian/anaconda3:/c/Users/Krystian/anaconda3/Library/mingw-w64/bin:/c/Users/Krystian/anaconda3/Library/usr/bin:/c/Users/Krystian/anaconda3/Library/bin:/c/Users/Krystian/anaconda3/Scripts:$PATH" so that it contains the correct Anaconda path.
